# How to run the AppBuilder to deploy a NativeScript application

Tags: ios, deployment, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I try to deploy my NativeScript application to my iOS device. I know there have been quite a few questions on this but I just can not get behind it.

What did I try to do?

I followed this tutorial:
http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/running-your-app/run-app-device

It tells me to install the AppBuilder - which I did (like mentioned [here](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/development-tools/running-appbuilder/running-the-cli/downloading-and-installing-cli), where I am told to simply run `sudo npm install appbuilder -g --unsafe-perm`). Executing this (in my project directory) it installs the appbuilder with the following message:

```
Autocompletion is already enabled
/usr/local/lib
└── appbuilder@3.7.5
```

So far so good, so I ran `appbuilder doctor`

```
WARNING: Mono 3.12 or later is not installed or not configured properly.
You will not be able to work with Android devices in the device simulator or debug on connected Android devices.
To be able to work with Android in the device simulator and debug on connected Android devices,
download and install Mono 3.12 or later from http://www.mono-project.com/download/

When you file an issue, these warnings will help the AppBuilder team to investigate, identify, and resolve the report.
Please, ignore them if you are not experiencing any issues with AppBuilder.
```

I ignored this warning, since I do not want to deploy to android (yet). So I went ahead on the tutorial and it told me I had to use code-signing of iOS-Apps. On [this](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/cordova/code-signing-your-app/configuring-code-signing-for-ios-apps/create-csr) side they tell me to meet the following prerequisites:

```
Verify that your preferred AppBuilder client is running and you are logged in.
Verify that you have opened the code for your app in AppBuilder.
```

Which is where I am already passing out. How do I run the AppBuilder? I thought that was just like NativeScript and I could access anything of it just via the Terminal (if necessary).

Comment: Instead of using the AppBuilder CLI, you should try the NativeScript CLI (or even better, [NativeScript Sidekick](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick).

Comment: If I go for `tns deploy ios --device <deviceID>` then he tells me the same thing (that I need to sign the App). Which led me to the appbuilder to sign it.

Comment: Do you want to just deploy it to a connected device? If so you can just `tns run ios` with the device connected (without having to provision the device).

Comment: I already tried this, he tells me that the code needs to be signed (sadly). Did I do something wrong there?

Comment: I apologize! I was getting iOS Simulator deployment confused with deploying to a physical device. There are some lengthy docs on iOS deployment [available here](https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/publishing-ios-apps#certificates-identifiers--profiles). Unfortunately Apple makes it all a bit difficult :(